# IDE for ROS? what should we build?

Tags: user-interface, ide, ros

Our group is developing an open source IDE for ROS ecosystem as whole, with GUI features and many more stuff built in, and I would like to ask the community whether is it required in your work flow..?

What are the things you do repeatedly and want to have an IDE to handle it..?

features?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really a question about a programming problem, but rather appears to be some sort of poll.

Comment: @Joey I have intended it as a question for is the community in need of an IDE, 

you can say it as a "yes or no" poll... ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following software [RTMAPS](https://intempora.com/), this is an IDE that we use in our robotic Lab typically for a rapid development and integration in windows & Linux. Lately, they have been working on ROS Integration as well, but still, it is proprietary and needing a license...

Basically, a good ROS IDE would be something alike, add nodes, specify inputs/outputs, nodes interconnections...

Btw, I am interested by that, do you need help ?

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I am looking into the software you mentioned, and will tell you as soon as I check it.